# How to design neo4j db nodes that have ordered relationship with other nodes

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to design a Neo4j graph database, and I will illustrate my specific requirement.  I'm designing an app that allows users to collaborate on the books and magazines they have read.  Requirements:

1. The same Book can be read by multiple people
2. The order in which a specific person reads the books is important.  For example, I want to be able to represent that Person A read Books B1 and B2 in that order, while Person B may have read Books B3, B2 and B1 in that order.

   I'm thinking of having nodes representing a Book, Magazine, Person, etc.

What is the best way to ensure the order/sequence information?  A couple of options I thought about:

1. Store a order ID or timestamp in the relationship between a Person and a Book node and use that to query all Books read by the person in the right order.
2. Store a Next/Previous relationship between Book nodes, but this approach will not work because the order can vary depending on which person read the books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this is the way to go, easy and effective.

> Store a order ID or timestamp in the relationship between a Person and
>   a Book node and use that to query all Books read by the person in the
>   right order.

Storing a Next/Previous relationship will not work, because you would have to save UserID in the NEXT relationship between books and that is just nonsense.

Comment: Thanks @Tomaz!  That's what I thought, and glad to know this is the "right" way.